# What does the button on Aquarium VI do?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I purchased the Aquarium VI at the same time as my fish, for fear of letting them die for not vising them enough. I've never noticed the aquarium before I purchased this upgrade, but there is a button on the Aquarium that simply states "Use".

Pressing this button has no noticeable effect, and doesn't become available again for quite some time. What does this "use" button do?

Comment: On the PC, as soon as you exit the quarters and return - the button is enabled again. :$

Answer (score 4):

In Mass Effect 3, an upgrade module for fish tanks, which automatically feeds and cares for the fish, is available for purchase at the Citadel for 25,000 credits.

Thanks to Tristan for commenting on this answer.

The real answer has been found, the button does feed the fish, but it is purely aesthetic after the VI is purchased.

Comment: The button DOES feed the fish. The button is made unnecessary by the VI purchase.

Comment: @SamuelStandrin Rather than leave all your edits in, I recommend editing your answer down to just the relevant text (which, effectively, becomes the same as Tristan's comment).

Comment: **Where** on the Citadel can you find the VI, by the way?

Comment: The Aquarium VI is available for purchase at the Elkoss Combine Arsenal Supplies terminal in the Presidum Commons of the Citadel for 25,000 credits.